# Laravel subdomaining is not working on the live server

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain

I have set up domain (domain.com) and subdomaining in a single project in Laravel. Subdomains are created dynamically. When I hit domain.com then it opens the main website correctly, but when I hit on test.domain.com then it is not working on the live server.
I am using laravel 6.18.13 version and PHP version in 7.3.

**Route File**
Routes/web.php

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.domain.com', 'middleware' => ['Subdomain']), function () {

Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image.

Comment: You need to do some more digging.  I assume you have purchased the domain and set up the DNS appropriately? Is your web server setup the same? Is there anything in your logs? How are you doing the multi tenacy, are you editing the web server conf?

Comment: ALWAYS put the exact error you are getting. "It's not working" could be a 1000 different things..